# C# - Найти максимальный элемент в каждой строке двумерного массива и заменить его на "."

Tags: c#

> Найти максимальный элемент в каждой строке двумерного массива и
>   заменить его на "."

```
Random ran = new Random();
int[,] myArr = new int[4, 5];
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <5; j++)
    {
         myArr[i, j] = ran.Next(1, 99);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в C# так не работает(хотя в некоторых других языках так можно написать).

C# язык со статической типизацией [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Статическая_типизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

В вашем случае вы не можете изменить тип вашего массива во время работы программы.

```
int[,] myArr = new int[4, 5];
```

Во в этой строчке, слева вы сказали(для упрощения), что переменная myArr принадлежит типу int[]. Теперь туда можно добавлять только числа и исправить это нельзя.

Вы дали очень мало описания и возможно не прочитали, как задавать вопросы. Нужно задать конкретный вопрос, ибо в данный момент он звучит "Я ничего не сделал, сделайте за меня"(поэтому вам ставят минусы, а не потому что вопрос плохой).

Для того, чтобы вам ответили, задайте конкретный вопрос. В данном случае он звучит "Как мне вставить в массив чисел символ?"

Дело в том, что это форум архив знаний, состоящий из вопросов. Вопрос и ответ должен содержать в себе страницу учебника. Представьте, что вы пишете Введение в тему занятия. В ответах пишутся детали, а в комментариях обсуждаете с коллегами, как лучше написать.

**Подсказка, как сделать**

Если правильно оформите вопрос, я на него отвечу. Пока пусто.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение моей ошибке в формулировке вопроса. Стоит задача в том, чтобы создать двухмерный массив целых чисел, и заменить каждый максимальный элемент на ".". Свою ошибку я уже понял. На данный момент появился вопрос в другом, как заменить максимальные элементы массива и вывести новый массив.

Comment: @Yaroslav Вот добавьте пока это все в вопрос. Если появляются какие-то уточнения, просто пишите UPD(как многие делают)

Comment: @Yaroslav я подготовил ответ, поправьте вопрос и я обновлю ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы можно было помещать одно нецелочисленное значение в массив, можно вместо типа `int[,]` использовать `int?[,]`. В таком случае в массив можно помещать `null`, что, по-моему, идеально подходит под описанную задачу. А уже при выводе вместо null выводить точку.

Пример, как заменить элемент `a[2,3]`: https://ideone.com/TvZEND

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Random ran = new Random();

    int n = 4, m = 5;
    int?[,] a = new int?[n, m];

    for (int q=0; q<n; ++q)
      for (int w=0; w<m; ++w)
        a[q, w] = ran.Next(0, 9);

    a[2, 3] = null;

    for (int q=0; q<n; ++q)
    {
      for (int w=0; w<m; ++w)
        Console.Write("{0} ", a[q, w]?.ToString() ?? ".");

      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 int maxindex=0, max=myArr[i, 0];
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <5; j++)
    {
         if(myArr[i, j]>max) 
         {
             max=myArr[i, j];
             maxindex=j;
         }
    myArr[i, maxindex]=10;
}
```

Comment: каждый раз при проходе первого цикла создавать переменные ? не проще ли их просто обнулять, чем создавать заного n раз?

Comment: Не вижу проблем.

Comment: эмм - ну ок. Просто это плохой подход, когда размерность массива возрастает.

Comment: Нет, не плохой.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka отличные парирования критики ;). А как думаете, каким будет результат Вашего кода, если все элементы в нем будут отрицательные (да, я вижу что у автора они не будут отрицательными)? И как Вы думаете, сработает ли Ваша предпоследняя строчка, или выбросит ошибку на этапе компиляции?

Comment: @Yaroslav, Зачем испортили ответ?

Comment: @Ep1demic думаю, сработает.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka попробуйте здесь http://rextester.com/ вставьте следующее `var arr = new int[4,5]; arr[0] = 10;`

Comment: @Ep1demic Это исправлено давно. Ну, в спешке было написано.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka не заметил, извините. Но остался еще один момент который можно улучшить в этом примере;) внутри первого цикла, перед вторым переменной *max* (исходя из примера автора) можно присваивать `var max = myArr[i,1]`, и цикл уже начинать со второго элемента (уменьшится к-ство операций...).

Comment: И убедить преподавателя, что автор вопроса написал весь этот профессиональный код (я о других ответах).